# How to express "I am not in the office" using one word?

Tags: word-choice

I am going to put a text board on the door of my office to show others that I am not in the office, when needed. Can I just write "Outed" on it? Any advice?

Comment: "Outed" is the past tense of the verb "to out".  You probably don't mean that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outing

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's one single English word for that phrase. From a quick internet search it looks like

> "Out of office"

is the most common sign, but if you absolutely cannot use multiple words,

> "Out"

is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

If you can only use one word, I would write "Out."

Also, I think you meant to say, "any advice." Advice is the noun. Advise is the verb you use when you are giving someone "advice." Example: I advised my brother to follow the good advice our father had given him.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. And if there is not limitation on number of word to use, what should I write on it? A single "out" seems like may cause misunderstanding...

Comment: Hi chongkai Lu . If you aren't limited, then follow Jess STJ's advice, and write "Out of Office" or "Out of the Office."

Comment: I have re-edited my question and I decide to use "Out of Office".Thanks again!

Comment: It is usually more helpful to say when you expect to be back in the office. "Back at 2 pm" or "Back on Tuesday".

Answer (score 0):

***Out of office*** is what you want to say if you're trying to be clear and formal. Just saying ***out*** is, however, completely normal and usual. Consider the dialogue:

> "Hey, is Carol there?"
>   "No, she's out at the moment. She'll be in this afternoon"

That applies whatever it is that she might be *in* or *out* of - a home, and office, a building, whatever. You can also see an example in *Peanuts* cartoons, where Lucy sets herself up as a psychiatrist with a little stall, and a sign saying "the doctor is in", with a card to flip over to "out".

Don't use *outed*, because that's the past tense of the verb *to out* and means something completely different. Generally speaking, it means to reveal something previously hidden about someone - and usually it's assumed, absent other context, to be about sexual orientation.